# Overwrite a symlink with a file copy in perl

Tags: perl, symlink

I thought I'd seen an answer to this question before, but after searching here and google I just can't find it.

How do you replace an existing symlink with a copy of the file it points to?  IE copy the source file over the link.

Start with this

```
/path/to/file.txt
/link/path/file.txt -> /path/to/file.txt
```

Then call something like `copy('/path/to/file.txt', '/link/path/file.txt');` and get this:

```
/path/to/file.txt
/link/path/file.txt
```

The reason i can't just use `copy()` is that it doesn't seem to support overwriting a symlink with its source file as it thinks they're the same thing and gives the error "XXXXX and YYYYY are identical (not copied)"

Is there a method like copy which can overwrite a symlink with a copy of its source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with a single command. Here's a solution that doesn't involve renaming (you should probably add in error checking):

```
$linkLoc = readlink('/link/path/file.txt');
unlink('/link/path/file.txt');
copy($linkLoc, '/link/path/file.txt');
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you may find it worthwhile to wrap this in a handy function.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the simplest method

Comment: No problem :) I should mention -- it's important to store the readlink output because if something goes wrong with the copy, you can always restore the link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a single function that can do this -- unless you write it yourself.

What I do is:

- Copy the file to a temporary in the same directory
- Unlink the file
- Rename the temporary to the original name

(with error checking on each step, of course).

If things go wrong, there's some risk that you'll nuke the symlink and fail to replace it, but the rename should be fairly safe (since it's in the same directory, it will be on the same filesystem / partition).